# How to find the points, in both polar coordinates and rectangular coordinates corresponding to the values.

Tags: calculus

$r=1+3sin(t)$

where $t=0,\pi/6, \pi/4,\pi/3,\pi/2,3\pi/4,\pi,3\pi/2,2\pi$

How to find the points, in both polar
coordinates and rectangular coordinates corresponding to the values.

Can anyone show how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For polar coordinates $(r,t)$ simply note that

- $t=0 \implies r =1$
- $t=\pi/6 \implies r =1+3/2$
- ...

and so on.

For cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ let use

- $x=r\cos t$
- $y= r \sin t$

Comment: Ok, after getting the values what should I do...   So, I need to substitute each t value right, then I will be getting the co-ordinates

Comment: @doe Yes exactly, firstly find the pairs (r,t) which are the polar coordianates the for each of these find the corresponding cartesian pair by the given relations.

Comment: @doe Note that the passage from polar to cartesian is simple whereas the passage from cartesian to polar is more difficult.

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by rectangular coordinates

Comment: @doe Rectangular coordinates are the standard (x,y) cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Can you tell what is r in the second part

Comment: r is the value from the first part for the coordinates we are considering